# How to acsess another page by JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom, copy, copy-paste

I just want to copy all texes in [shizyab.ir/rand.php](https://shizyab.ir/rand.php)  and paste it to my html file by javascript. What shoud I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a version that does not require jquery:

```
function insertPage() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        var element = document.createElement("div");
        element.innerHTML = this.responseText;
        document.body.appendChild(element);
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://www.shizyab.ir/rand.php", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

And to run this code: `insertPage();`

Answer (score 0):

You could do that by using an ajax call with jquery in a script on `window.onload`:
Assuming your php script returns a json object.

```
function getData(username, callback) {
    var url = 'shizyab.ir/rand.php';
    $.ajax({
        url:(url),
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: (data) => {
           callback(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Then handle your data display in `callback` function.

Comment: this makes use of jquery. a pure native solution would be better